# Least cost path with multiple points

Tags: r, gis

I am trying to connect bivariate location points together to form a route. My points refer to fish locations, and so I need paths that only pass through water, and not the surrounding land. Basically, I need to do multiple least cost path analyses and join them altogether. I would like to do this in R, as I have more experience there than I do with ArcGIS, python, modelbuilder, etc.

I have used ArcGIS to create a cost surface, with water coded as 0 and land coded as "NoData", and have imported this into R.

I have tried using shortestPath from the gdistance pkg, but R always shuts down on me when I try running it even just between two points. For example:

```
costpath=shortestPath(costtrans,c29924[1,],c29924[2,],output="SpatialLines")
```

where my cost surface is "costtrans", and "c29924" is a SpatialPointsDataFrame with my lat/long locations. I had planned to run a loop so that I could do this for each row in the data frame. However, I do not know why R is not handling even one iteration well. When converting my cost surface to a transition object for the first arguements, I do receive the following warning messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: In array(ans, c(len.a%/%d2, d.ans), if (!all(vapply(dn.ans, is.null,  :
Reached total allocation of 6057Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In array(ans, c(len.a%/%d2, d.ans), if (!all(vapply(dn.ans, is.null,  :
Reached total allocation of 6057Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In as.vector(transition.values) :
Reached total allocation of 6057Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In as.vector(transition.values) :
Reached total allocation of 6057Mb: see help(memory.size)
5: In .TM.repl.i.mat(as(x, "TsparseMatrix"), i = i, value = value) :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Any suggestions for solving this, or other approaches to my initial goal would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to do this using the `gdistance` package.  Can you report the dimensions of your raster -- it could be a memory problem.  `shortestPath()` and `costDistance()` both need `TransitionLayer` objects, so if you are not able to produce these, it won't work.  If it is, indeed, a memory limitation, consider upscaling your raster using `aggregate()` from the `raster` package.

Comment: It could also be your cost surface parameterization that is causing these errors (cost surface needs to be a conductance surface, so 1/cost).  If you don't want paths to cross land set land to 0.00001, and set water to 1.  This will cause the paths to avoid land, and give the geographic path length in raster units between points on water only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to do what you wish using the `gdistance` package.  It may be an issue with the size of your raster (i.e. it is too big for memory), in which case you can upscale it with `aggregate()` from the `raster` package.  It may also be an issue with your parameterization of land and sea as noted in another comment.

Here is an example of what I believe you want to achieve (below).  I have parameterized the land as a high cost barrier (=10000 cost units), and the sea as no barrier (=1 cost unit).  Note also that I take the inverse to produce a conductance surface.  If you want the lengths of the paths between locations, it can be done with `costDistance()` and this will give you the result as a geographic path length in the units of the raster.

```
library(gdistance)

## Create cost surface where "land" exists in the middle
cost <- raster(nrow=100, ncol=100, 
           xmn=0, xmx=100, ymn=0, ymx=100, crs="+proj=utm")
cost[] <- 1
cost[cellFromRowColCombine(cost, 50:55,20:80)] <- 10000

## Produce transition matrices, and correct because 8 directions
trCost <- transition(1/cost, mean, directions=8)
trCost <- geoCorrection(trCost, type="c")

## Create three points (representing three points in time series)
pts <- cbind(x=c(20, 60, 40), y=c(80, 60, 20))

## Display results
plot(cost)
plot(SpatialPoints(pts), add=TRUE, pch=20, col="red")
text(pts[,1]+2, pts[,2]+2, 1:nrow(pts))
plot(shortestPath(trCost, pts[1,], pts[2,], output="SpatialLines"), add=TRUE)
plot(shortestPath(trCost, pts[2,], pts[3,], output="SpatialLines"), add=TRUE)
```

[image: Example plot of least-cost paths around land]

Comment: Thanks PaulG - your post is super helpful. I didn't know about aggregate() for rasters, and I think this may be what is causing trouble. I initially had a very high resolution raster, so I think I will have to sacrifice some of the resolution to get my shortestPaths.

Comment: I'm still having an issue with R...it stops working when I try shortestPath(). I have tried aggregating my raster so that there are 1000x fewer cells, but I still face this problem. Could this be because I am trying to find the shortest path between two points that may now be in the same cell after aggregating?

Comment: If you are giving `shortestPath()` a corrected `TransitionLayer` object it should work.  Have you updated R and the package to the newest versions?  Also, check that you have no NAs or other oddities in your coordinates?  Try the same for your cost layer e.g. `unique(cost)`, you could try setting NA cells to 1 if they exist `cost[is.na(cost)]` <- 1.  Finally, check to see if the raster is residing in memory or on disk.  You may be able to force it into memory with `cost[] <- getValues(cost)`

Comment: I have no NAs in my cost raster, or my coordinates. I will try your memory vs disk suggestion.

Comment: Check that you haven't obliterated your cost raster by downsampling it `plot(cost)`.  Failing that I have run out of ideas.  You can try posting what is certainly a bug on the R-sig-geo list https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-geo.

Comment: I haven't obliterated it, it's more fuzzy for sure, but I can still make out the coastline, which is all I need. I guess I'll be posting the bug...

Comment: I switched from using RStudio to the base version, and now when I enter shortestPath I get an error: > costpath=shortestPath(trCost,c29924[1,],c29924[2,],output="SpatialLines")
Error in get.shortest.paths(adjacencyGraph, indexOrigin, indexGoal) : 
  At type_indexededgelist.c:1237 : cannot get neighbors, Invalid vertex id

Comment: Right now I have land coded as 999 and water as 1. Should I try switching these? I thought 999 would be assumed to be a huge cost...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree), where the cost on each edge is a function of distance and other factors. In your case, set the weight to infinity if an edge crosses non-water, making sure it never gets used unless they are required at the end to connect the graph. If the graph is non-connected, you can run two or more minimum spanning trees on each disconnected group of points. See wikipedia for easily implemented algorithms, notably [Prim's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) algorithm.

Comment: I am going to look into your suggestions Benjamin - which R packages do you suggest if I decide to go this route?

Comment: No specific packages in mind, it would be fairly simple to code your own implementation.

Comment: I don't have tons of experience with graph theory, so I have a feeling this will be a big undertaking...

Comment: Run a search on CRAN for "minimum spanning tree", it will list a few packages that implement this.

Comment: I have begun searching the topic. My main concern is that I won't retain the time component of my locations. Right now, they are all in order from oldest to newest, and I would like to connect them as such, to show a movement path.

Comment: So it's not really a least cost path, then? Just a time-series of locations?

Comment: Yes, it's an irregular time-series of locations. I only investigated cost-path because using Euclidean distance tools in GIS to connect the points meant that routes crossed over land. Cost path seemed to be a way to create paths solely in the water.

Comment: The selective approach you are taking with `gdistance` will allow you to keep the time order (although it is not very computationally efficient).

Comment: Maybe try zeros and ones, instead of zeros and NoData. R might handle it better.