# In R - How to calculate the distance between points following the coastal line

Tags: r, distance, gis

In the next lines I expose my big problem, maybe is big because I have only a few R lessons.

I'm calculating distance between geographical points using its coordinates, by `gDistance()` of rgeos package. But I need to calculate the distance between points only by over sea (no crossing over earth) I can´t.

So you imagine that we have two points around an island and you need the distances between points along the coastal line, without cross the island, and the island´s shore is irregular.

Maybe I can modify the `gDistance()` code to do it? or someone know another option?

Thank you very much and your help is very appreciated!

Comment: This isn't going to lead to a [Coastline Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox), is it? :)

Comment: I don't think there's a trivial answer to this ("modify gDistance"). I bookmarked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605827/least-cost-path-with-multiple-points) post a while ago - maybe it gives you some ideas in connection with a coastline shapefile.

Comment: You may be worth looking at the answer to this question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595414/calculate-distance-between-2-lon-lats-but-avoid-going-through-a-coastline-in-r

Comment: Dear Sebastian-c, many thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I'm not working with Coastline Paradox. Thank you.

Comment: @Jose are you still active?  I answered a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595414/calculate-distance-between-2-lon-lats-but-avoid-going-through-a-coastline-in-r/28664365#28664365